# Error: failed to download "xxx" (hint: running `helm repo update` may help)

Tags: java, kubernetes, deployment, containers, kubernetes-helm

I am trying to see the details (values, etc) of an existing helm-chart using:

> `helm show values xxx -n namespace`

Getting Error:

> `` failed to download "xxx" (hint: running `helm repo update` may help) ``

What should I do to fix this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `helm -n <namespace> get values <release-name>` to get the values of installed  chart.

Comment: It is possible to edit these values?

Comment: @Justin These values are generated through your deployment files and helm support files. You can easily update and reinstall the chart.